# How to deploy the application of bodgeit store on Heroku

Tags: javascript, java, heroku

the bodgeit store (https://bodgeit.herokuapp.com) was running on that same url. now its not working and I wanted to host it again but new for Heroku.

Here is the GitHub link for that application (https://github.com/psiinon/bodgeit). I tried deploying it on herokuapp but it failed with error "not able to identify Buildpack"

Can you please tell me that process to deploy it on Heroku app?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried following the excellent step-by-step deployment documentation that Heroku provides? Also, [this is literally the second link if you Google it](https://help.heroku.com/1MC2J0GF/why-does-my-app-fail-to-detect-a-buildpack).

Comment: Yes tried but as I said, I am new for Heroku. so unable to understand everything. the same code was installed on Heroku and it was running.

Comment: Yes, but we can't really tell you anymore than the documentation does, and that link I posted.

Comment: thanks for that :) trying to get more with documentation